# Cannot receive data-only messages on iOS running Flutter client in the foreground

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I cannot receive data-only Firebase messages on my Flutter iOS client when my application is in the foreground. I have been experimenting with this for days without success.

Data+notification messages do work (when my app is in the foreground) and are successfully received by my `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` event handler. On Android, everything works as expected.

Flutter configuration:

- `firebase_core: ^2.10.0`
- `firebase_messaging: ^14.4.1`

I am sending Firebase data-only messages from a PHP page using `firebase-php` 6.9.5 using the following code:

```
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget(MessageTarget::TOKEN, $registrationToken);
$message = $message->withData($data);
```

I have also tried to add:

```
$message = $message->withApnsConfig(['headers' => [
            'apns-priority' => '5',
            "apns-topic" => 'io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging'
        ]);
```

as setting an `apns-priority` of exactly the value of 5 seems to be the way to go for data-only messages. Not sure about `apns-topic` but included anyway.
But this does not work either.

Please note that `firebase-php` version 6.9.5 automatically adds the `content-available` key with a value of 1 to the payload and `apns-push-type` (value: 'background') to the headers when sending data-only messages for iOS, as mentionned here:

https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/700

I traced the PHP code and verified this is indeed the case.

No matter what I do, I cannot get a data-only message received on the Flutter iOS client side.